# How to dynamically change templateUrl of directive from controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to pass the templateUrl for app_modal directive from controller "ServerController" so that the same directive can be used for different modals having different template. So i have included the url as the attribute for "app-modal" tag which is used in the server_group.html view. And i am returning that url from templateUrl property of directive. But it is throwing the below error -

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'protocol' of undefined
at urlIsSameOrigin (http://localhost/js/:30578:17)
at $http (http://localhost/js/:24316:23)
at Function.$get.$http.(anonymous function) (http://localhost/js/:24533:18)
at compileTemplateUrl (http://localhost/js/:23130:13)
at applyDirectivesToNode (http://localhost/js/:22755:24)
at compileNodes (http://localhost/js/:22354:15)
at compileNodes (http://localhost/js/:22366:15)
at compile (http://localhost/js/:22287:15)
at compile (http://localhost/js/:38714:15271)
```

Directive for Modal -

```
 angular.module("app")

    .directive("appModal", function() {
        return {
            restrict: "E",
            replace: true,
            scope: {
                modal: "=modalBody"
            },
            templateUrl: function(element, attrs) {
                return attrs.templateUrl;                  
            }                
        };

    });
```

**Controller -**

```
function ServerController($scope) {

    $scope.confirmDelete = {

        body: "Are you sure you want to delete?",
        primaryBtn: "Delete",
        cancel: "Cancel",
        templateUrl: "pages/DRaaS/app/ServerGroup/partials/app_modal.html"

    };
```

}

Html -

```
<app-modal modal-body="confirmDelete" templateUrl="pages/DRaaS/app/ServerGroup/partials/app_modal.html"><app-modal>
```

Comment: be careful with uppercase in attributes. angular will read `some-attribute="foo"` as `attrs.someAttribute` in directive code. try simplifying your attribute to lowercase or `template-url`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `templateUrl` function runs, the scope is not available and the attribute values are still not interpolated. So, if you have something like:

```
<foo param="{{a}}"></foo>
```

then in `templateUrl` you will get the string `"{{a}}"` for `attrs.param` - not the value of `$scope.a`.

Instead, you'd need to accept the template url as a variable (ideally via isolated scope) to the directive. Inside the directive you could cheaply use `ng-include` bound to that value.

```
.directive("appModal", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      modal: "=modalBody",
    },
    template: '<div ng-include="modal.templateUrl"></div>'
  };
});
```

The usage is as you suggest:

```
<app-modal modal-body="confirmDelete"></app-modal>
```

And in the controller:

```
$scope.confirmDelete = {
  // other properties,
  templateUrl: "path/to/template.html"
}
```