# Is there any ways to update directive link with scope or some other values?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have `dC` directive

```
app.directive('dC', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'AE',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {},
        templateUrl: function(elem, attrs) {
            return $rootScope.somePosiT
        }
    }
});
```

And I want to access inside of my controller as function is there anyway can I achieve it in order to change my directive location dynamically when click fired

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
        clk: function() {
            $rootScope.somePosiT = 'views/1.html'
        }
})
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to dynamically change templateUrl of directive from controller](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28139250/how-to-dynamically-change-templateurl-of-directive-from-controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could do it using template and ng-include - rather than templateUrl. I think templateUrl is called before the scope values are available. You could try something like this:

```
app.directive('dC', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'AE',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {},
    template: '<div ng-include="somePosiT"></div>'
  };
});

app.controller('appCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.clk = {
    somePosiT: "path/to/template.html"
  };
});
```

Comment: How can I say thank you. It worked I could not find the answer to this about 3 hours now and it worked. Thank you

Comment: @Shaxrillo Glad to be of help :-)